# rem works fine with font-size but does NOT work fine with margin if I set 10px font-size to html tag

Tags: html, css, margin, font-size

As we know, `rem` is widely used to achieve a responsive layout.

But I found that it works different to `font-size` and `margin`.

First let's set `font-size:16px` to `html`, and set `font-size:2rem; margin:2rem;` to `p`. It works fine this time, both `font-size` and `margin` are calculated to `32px`.

But if we set `font-size:10px` to `html`, `font-size` is correctly calculated to `20px`, however, `margin` is calculated to `24px`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/peKKZY

[image: codepen screenshot]

OS: MacOS Sierra 10.12.2 (16C67)
Browser: Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

---

I know that Chrome has a default minimum `font-size` as `12px`. But it's weird that `font-size` and `margin` works different.

I tried to set `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` but it doesn't work because from chrome version 28.0.1500.11 chrome doesn't support -webkit-text-size-adjust anymore (changelist is here: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/145168)

It would be perfect if we can set `font-size:10px` to `html`, because it's more easy to set other rem values.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Testing your pen in exactly the same Chrome version number, only on Windows 7, gives me calculated values of 20px for the margins ... looks like this is simply a browser bug in the Mac version ...?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your testing, I'll send a feedback to Chrome team

Answer (score 1):

Your pen works perfectly in Chrome 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit) on MacOS Sierra. This must have been a Chrome bug that was already addressed.[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I updated my Chrome version to 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit) but the issue style exist. I double checked the Chrome version and the codepen demo. Are you sure the margin is 20px in your Chrome?